# Proof that square of a standard normal r.v. has Chi-Square Distribution using MGF's

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, moment-generating-function, chi-squared-distribution, method-of-moments

Supposes $Z \sim N(0,1)$. We know that $Z^{\top}\!Z\sim\text{Chi-Square}(1)$. Does the proof for this concept require the use of moment generating functions/method of moments per say?

Comment: Usually, the chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom is **defined as** the distribution of $X_1^2+\dots+X_n^2$ when $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n$ are iid standar normal distributed, so then there is nothing to show!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I'm not really sure that's true, but if it was the $\chi^2$ distribution still has a specific form, so the poster would want to know how to derive it.

Comment: @dsaxton: Yes, of course. But I am surte that was the original definition of the chi-aquare distribution, and the reason for it beeing of any interest at all!

Answer (score 3):

No. It doesn't *require* either, since you can show it without using MGFs.

With only a single standard normal where $Z^\top\!Z=Z^2$ you can show it exactly via that transformation. You should be able to write down the density of $|Z|$ (by inspection) and so use elementary considerations (go from $P(|Z|\leq t)$ to $P(Z^2\leq t^2)$ to the density for $Z^2$)  or standard methods (like the change of variable formula) to find the density of its square.

(For equality of moments to show equality of distribution you'd have to show the MGF exists in a neighborhood around zero.)

Comment: @stats555: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_related_to_chi-squared_distribution

Comment: If I obtain the probability density function of a Normal or Standard Normal, how would I obtain the density function of a Chi-Square?

Comment: My answer states two approaches. You haven't seen [change of variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables)? You can prove it from fairly elementary considerations.