# Exhibiting the relation between Z and $\chi^2$

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, chi-squared-test

I am trying to prove that if the random variable Z $\sim$  N(0,1) ,then $Z^2 = \chi^2(1)$. I thought that the best method is to use graphs, so I wrote that

```
    curve((dnorm(x,mean=0,sd=1)^2))
```

After that , to see the graph of $\chi^2$, I wrote that

```
 curve(dchisq(x, df = 1))
```

However, those are not same graphs. My question is why are the graphs not the same? What am I missing? And how can I show their relations using computer programs if my method is wrong? By the way, I prefer the R language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof that square of a standard normal r.v. has Chi-Square Distribution using MGF's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186991/proof-that-square-of-a-standard-normal-r-v-has-chi-square-distribution-using-mg)

Comment: @Xi'an i am mainly interested in why my method does not work ,

Comment: @Xi'an i thought that the graphs must be same , but they are not

Comment: It would help if you said what you use as `x` and posted the two plots you create.

Comment: The discrepancy comes from your (incorrect) assumption that the pdf of a continuous RV $Y = g(X)$ is $f_Y(y) = g(f_X(y)).$ To see that your formulation is incorrect, note that `dnorm(x)^2` will not integrate to 1. See [these notes](https://www.math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf) for the correct formula. The correction to your R code is `curve(dnorm(sqrt(x), 0, 1) / (sqrt(x)))`

Comment: Since the largest value attained by `dnorm` is $1/\sqrt{2\pi}\approx 0.4,$ by squaring it you are multiplying the area under the curve by a value no greater than this: in other words, you are (greatly) reducing its area.  Since the area *must* be $1,$ according to the axioms of probability, this can't be correct.  For the right way to proceed, see [our posts on transforming variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pdf+density+jacobian).

Comment: You cannot prove your desired result by looking at graphs. How could you possibly know if two graphs are identical? You must use logic and correct mathematics to do the proof.

Comment: @AdrianKeister: Visual proofs are maybe not proofs, but they can still be helpful!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes, of course, but I don't think graphs will be at all helpful in this case. The desired statement-to-prove is already known, and I don't think any relevant plot would help nudge anyone in the right direction for the proof.

Comment: @AdrianKeister, I have to disagree with you there! Creating these visual aids immediately lead to OP realizing that they have a misconception about transformation of variables. You can't prove something that you don't understand.

Comment: @knrumsey Well, that's a fair point; however, it's "negative progress", as in, the OP figured out another way not to make a light bulb, as Edison would say. How could visual aids prompt someone not just away from a wrong direction, but in a right direction?

Answer (score 2):

*Graphical comment:* You could use the PDF transformation method to show that when $X\sim\mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ then $X^2 \sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=1).$
You could also use moment generating functions.

If you want a graphical approach, it may be best to do use a simulation--not as a formal proof, but as a practical demonstration. It seems you are using R; I will too.

```
set.seed(2022)
x = rnorm(10^5, 0, 1)
y = x^2

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="n=10000: Standard Normal")
  curve(dnorm(x), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
 hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2", main="n=10000: CHISQ(1)")
  curve(dchisq(x,1), add=T, lwd=2, col="orange")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]